# Open Outlook with <h:commandButton>

Tags: email, jsf, hyperlink, outlook

What is the corresponding JSF code for

```
<a href="mailto:me@domain.com?subject=Sample subject&body=test&cc=cc@domain.com">Send mail</a>
```

which opens Outlook mail box to the user with the mail template prefilled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're on JSF 1.2 or newer, you can just use the very same HTML code in a JSF page.

```
<a href="mailto:me@domain.com?subject=Sample subject&body=test&cc=cc@domain.com">Send mail</a>
```

If you intend to prefill it based on values form a JSF form, then you need to send a redirect to exactly that URL.

```
public void submit() throws IOException {
    // ...

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect(String.format(
        "mailto:me@domain.com?subject=%s&body=%s&cc=cc@domain.com",
            URLEncoder.encode(subject, "UTF-8"),
            URLEncoder.encode(body, "UTF-8")));
}
```

Please note that this doesn't necessarily prepare the mail in Outlook. It merely prepares the mail in client's own default mail client, which may not be Outlook per se. It may for instance be Thunderbird or even Gmail. Also note that you have *no* control over that part.